# Setting up SSRS 2016 to use office 365 SMTP server

Tags: email, ssrs-2016

Within the configuration screens for SSRS 2016 you are now able to specify a username and password to allow connection to a secure smtp server.

I've been trying to configure it to use `smtp.office365.com` with basic authentication selected and secure connection checked. I've set up an email subscription within SSRS which when executed results in the following error:

> Failure sending mail: Command not implemented. The server response
>   was: 5.3.3 Command not implementedMail will not be resent.

But if I change the configuration to utilise `smtp.mail.yahoo.com` with the same settings, the email is sent without issue. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what might be causing the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Setting the port number to 587 within the rsreportserver.config file  has resolved the issue